# Find the position of a marker in a string relative to another

Tags: ruby, algorithm, text, substring

I've got two strings, one sanitized and one with a `MARKER`. This `MARKER` is a fixed string  and is chosen arbitrary, inserted into the String by some other code.

```
 sanitized = "100 biz other stuff"
 marked = " 100    biz MARKER other stuff"
```

Now match the surroundings of the `MARKER` with the `sanitized`
string.

```
 # _ is empty, the string is expanded for visual only
 sanitized =  "100 ___biz_______ other stuff"
 marked =    " 100    biz MARKER other stuff"
```

And get the index of the `MARKER` in the `sanitized` string.

```
 sanitized =  "100 ___biz_MARKER other stuff"
                          ^
 marked =    " 100    biz MARKER other stuff"
```

Which would be `7`.

Comment: In your second example, I can match "Subsidiarität" in marked String. Now here the sanitation has removed "Art. 5aMARKER". I know the MARKER exists here, but I cannot possibly predict where. Maybe you could explain that.

Comment: No, there is no way to predict it. Probably a longest substring could do the job.

Comment: So what is your question? How to merge strings? What are your criteria for a successful merge? If I have two strings "abc" and "def", and I merge them to "xyz", am I right? If not, why not?

Comment: So basically the answer will be - it lies somewhere in "Art. 5aMARKER". Unless you define the sanitation function, this cannot be done. Maybe I didn't understand the question completely!

Comment: why do you have those extra spaces in the marked string? also, you have an extra space for MARKER. it's quite confusing. is `MARKER` a literal fixed string, or just an example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you're asking either. It sounds like you just need to know how to find the location of a string inside of a string.

```
virtual = "100 biz MARKER other stuff"
virtual.index 'MARKER'
# => 8
```

Comment: Yes, but the virtual string does not exist, it's just an example. You only have the `sanitized` and the `marked` string.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very ambiguous, but this might help:

```
s = "100 biz other stuff"
m = s.match(/(100 biz )(other stuff)/)
m.offset(1)
=> [0, 8]
m.offset(2)
=> [8, 19]
s.insert(m.offset(1)[1], "MARKER ")
=> "100 biz MARKER other stuff"
```